# Program where user enters 2 inputs and a limit. It finds the sum of the multiples. please check

Tags: java

The user must enter x, y, and the limit.  The program must find the multiples of these numbers that are below the limit that the user set themselves.  The program adds up all the multiples and prints just that number at the end, and not all the multiples.  For some reason it just isn't working for me and I can't figure it out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumMultiples.java {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter x value: ");
        int x = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter y value: ");  
        int y = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter limit value: ");
        int limit = scanner.nextInt()

        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            if (((i % x) == 0 || ((i % y) == 0))) {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should be more specific on what exactly you want to do. What does the limit do? We dont know...

Comment: Is there a problem here, or are you just asking for advice? StackOverflow is not the appropriate medium for the latter.

Comment: You may find http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ a better place for posting this kind of Question...

Comment: your class should not be called "SumMultiples.java"

Comment: I added some more details.  I apologize for the lack of them. I am new to this site and this is my first post! I just need to know what is wrong with it because I can't figure it out.

Comment: @TactMayers: "just isn't working for me" is a good indication that it doesn't belong on Code Review.  We expect code to be in working condition, and the OP must already see it as working.

Answer (score 1):

From copying your code into Eclipse:

Firstly you are missing a `;` when you are getting the input for `limit`.

Secondly your `System.out.println(sum);` is outside of your `main` method, it should be at the end of the method i.e. after your `for` loop.

Thirdly, you have named your class `SumMultiples.java`. This is not a valid name, rename it to `SumMultiples`.

You should be getting compile errors and your IDE should help you work this out. If you aren't using an IDE, please do so as it will help you debug these issues and help you get familiar with Java.